# Magento2: Delivery date - how to uncheck required

Tags: magento2, delivery

We use delivery date:
https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-delivery-date/tree/master/SR/DeliveryDate

Currently this field is required. Any solution how to uncheck to set this filed not required?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code from remove required field

> **/code/SR/DeliveryDate/Observer/SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBefore.php**

```
<?php
namespace SR\DeliveryDate\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository;
use SR\DeliveryDate\Model\Validator;

class SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBefore implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var QuoteRepository
     */
    private $quoteRepository;

    /**
     * @var Validator
     */
    private $validator;

    /**
     * SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBefore constructor.
     *
     * @param QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
     * @param Validator $validator
     */
    public function __construct(
        QuoteRepository $quoteRepository,
        Validator $validator
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    /**
     * @param EventObserver $observer
     * @return $this
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId());
        if (empty($order))
        {
        $order->setDeliveryDate($quote->getDeliveryDate());
        }

        $order->setDeliveryDate($quote->getDeliveryDate());
        $order->setDeliveryComment($quote->getDeliveryComment());

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

Please see this commit in your shared extension https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-delivery-date/commit/50eaa5e798b2cfd08c7e60d5117b577d9b7a93df it seems this extension control whether the field is required or not based on the store configuration.

```
const XPATH_REQUIRED_DELIVERY_DATE = 'sr_deliverydate/general/required_delivery_date';
```

We can find the configuration below.

```
Admin -> Store -> Configuration -> Order Delivery Date Settings -> Extension Settings -> Required Delivery Date
```

**Updates:** As per the comments you put, it seems observer **sales_model_service_quote_submit_before** didn't check store configuration before throw exception so for the quick fix I have added that logic

```
<?php
namespace SR\DeliveryDate\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository;
use SR\DeliveryDate\Model\Validator;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

class SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBefore implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var QuoteRepository
     */
    private $quoteRepository;

    /**
     * @var Validator
     */
    private $validator;

    /**
     * @var Validator
     */
    private $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBefore constructor.
     *
     * @param QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
     * @param Validator $validator
     */
    public function __construct(
        QuoteRepository $quoteRepository,
        Validator $validator,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->validator = $validator;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    /**
     * @param EventObserver $observer
     * @return $this
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId());

        // get the store configuration about required settings
        $is_required = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('sr_deliverydate/general/required_delivery_date', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

        //if it is not required and the value is empty/null then return the value without any changes.print $quote->getDeliveryDate() and then update if condition as per your need
        if(!$is_required && $quote->getDeliveryDate()==''){
            return $this;
        }

        // if it is required or not required, but customer enter the value so validate the value and return the exception
        if (!$this->validator->validate($quote->getDeliveryDate())) {
            throw new \Exception(__('Invalid Delevery Date'));
        }

        $order->setDeliveryDate($quote->getDeliveryDate());
        $order->setDeliveryComment($quote->getDeliveryComment());

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I hope it gives some idea.

**Note:** I didn't install this module, I just reviewed the code you shared and update the answer.

Comment: Yes, I set this option in backend. DeliveryDate is required: no. After save in last step checkout during select payment method impossible finish order. In log file I see: incorrect DeliveryDate

Comment: have you flushed the config cache? test it in a private window.

Comment: Yes, cache cleaned. For information: this option in module is set directly after install extension. DeliveryDate required: no

Comment: please post the log details with a full trace?  are you using php-fpm? if yes we need to restart fpm as well. Similarly check varnish, redis.

Comment: [2020-04-26 17:56:03] main.CRITICAL: Invalid Delevery Date {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Invalid Delevery Date at /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/app/code/SR/DeliveryDate/Observer/SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBefore.php:46)"} []

Comment: Screen issue: https://prnt.sc/s6ai7t

Comment: We do not use redis/ varnish cache. php-fmp  restarted but no result.